# Disable all buttons and inputs in Grid - XAML

Tags: c#, xaml

I build a windows store app and I have the following xaml:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"    Margin="413,138,438,0" Height="550" Width="515" x:Name="FormContainer">

    <TextBox Margin="133,249,131,269" PlaceholderText="Email" BorderBrush="#FF755CB0" BorderThickness="1" Opacity="0.9" x:Name="Email"/>

    <PasswordBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="133,298,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="251" Height="8" PlaceholderText="Password"  BorderBrush="#FF755CB0" BorderThickness="1" Opacity="0.9" x:Name="Password"/>
    <Button Content="Login" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,358,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="257" Height="50" Background="#FF235085" BorderBrush="#FF6749AC" BorderThickness="1" Foreground="White" Opacity="0.9" RequestedTheme="Light" Click="Login_Click"/>
    <TextBlock Margin="133,434,131,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="95" Width="251" FontSize="15" Foreground="Red" FontWeight="Light" x:Name="ErrorsPlaceholder" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

I want that when I click the button all the inputs and the button istelf will be enabled. Is there any way to do it that is not bu specify each element and diable is seperately?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

View:

```
<UserControl x:Class="LoginView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="EnabledStyle" TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LoggingIn}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <StackPanel x:Name="FormContainer" Style="{StaticResource EnabledStyle}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox x:Name="Email" Text="sample@email.net"/>
            <PasswordBox x:Name="Password" Password="password"/>
            <Button x:Name="LoginButton" Content="{Binding LoginButtonText, Mode=OneWay}" Click="OnLogin"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Errors" Text="Sample Error Message"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Code Behind:

```
    public partial class LoginView : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public LoginView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        LoggedIn = true;
        OnLogin(null, null);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public string LoginButtonText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(LoginButtonTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LoginButtonTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LoginButtonTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("LoginButtonText", typeof(string), typeof(LoginView));

    public bool LoggedIn
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(LoggedInProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LoggedInProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for LoggedIn.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LoggedInProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("LoggedIn", typeof(bool), typeof(LoginView), new PropertyMetadata(OnLoggedIn));

    static void OnLoggedIn(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var view = (LoginView)o;
        if (view == null) return;

        view.LoggedIn=(bool)e.NewValue;
        view.LoginButtonText = view.LoggedIn ? "Logoff" : view.LoggingIn ? "Logging In ..." : "Login";

        view.RaisePropertyChanged("LoginButtonText");
        view.RaisePropertyChanged("LoggedIn");
    }

    public bool LoggingIn
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(LoggingInProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LoggingInProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LoggingInProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("LoggingIn", typeof(bool), typeof(LoginView), new PropertyMetadata(OnLoggingIn));

    static void OnLoggingIn(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var view = (LoginView)o;
        if (view == null) return;

        view.LoggingIn=(bool)e.NewValue;
        view.LoginButtonText = view.LoggedIn ? "Logoff" : view.LoggingIn ? "Logging In ..." : "Login";

        view.RaisePropertyChanged("LoginButtonText");
        view.RaisePropertyChanged("LoggingIn");
    }

    void OnLogin(object _, RoutedEventArgs __)
    {
        if (LoggedIn)
        {
            LoggedIn = false;
            LoggingIn = false;
        }
        else
        {
            LoggingIn = true;
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(3000); // simulating logon
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    LoggedIn = true;
                    LoggingIn = false;
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I put a three second delay in to simulate a log in, during which time the controls will all be disabled while the button shows "Logging In ...", after which the button will show "Logoff". If you click the button again, it goes back to saying "Login".